# For loop to buffer shapefile at multiple distances, add each to the layers window, style & save to geopackage; PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, buffer, for-loop

Can someone help me straighten this code out. I want to create three buffers, at 100, 250 and 500m respectively and add these to the contents table. I've tried creating a for loop but not having success. I'm a beginner with Python and the PyQGIS API.

Ideally, I wouldn't have to define the filepath of the outputs, rather save them to the geopackage from which the Layer_to_buffer originates), and I would also like to set the style of each buffered layer.

```
from qgis import processing
fn = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_to_buffer')[0]
Output = 'C:/Users/User/Filepath/Buffer'


for x in [100, 250, 500]:
    processing.run("native:buffer",\
      {'INPUT':lyr,\
       'DISTANCE':x,\
       'SEGMENTS':99,\
       'END_CAP_STYLE':0,\
       'JOIN_STYLE':0,\
       'MITER_LIMIT':2,\
       'DISSOLVE':True,\
       'OUTPUT': Output + str(x) +".shp"})
    iface.addVectorLayer(Output, '', 'ogr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inlayer = iface.activeLayer()

for dis in [500, 250, 100]:
    out_gpkg = inlayer.source().split('|')[0]
    outlayer = 'ogr:dbname=\'{0}\' table="buffer_{1}" (geom)'.format(out_gpkg, dis)
    processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", 
    {'INPUT':inlayer,
    'DISTANCE':dis,
    'SEGMENTS':5,
    'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
    'JOIN_STYLE':0,
    'MITER_LIMIT':2,
    'DISSOLVE':False,
    'OUTPUT':outlayer})
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens, I get this in the console window: exec(open('C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp_092ixq5.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())

Comment: Have you clicked/highlighted your layer to buffer to make it the active layer? Do you have a geopackage input (why are you adding .shp in your code)?

Comment: Yes I have. Thank you, it has added the three buffers to my geopackage, but it hasn't added them to the contents table. Are you able to break down the code a little so I can adapt it and edit the styles?

Comment: @BERA interestingly, it didn't work and I didn't expect that. After running the script, `.shx` and `.prj` files of `inlayer` are deleted from the folder and QGIS throws `........ Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.)` error.

Comment: Ok I only tested with a geopackage input and that worked

Comment: -inlayer:shapefile, -output:geopackage -> not working... -inlayer:shapefile, -output:shapefile -> working.